# How to select incoming notification of android app in python script

Tags: android, python, appium

I am using python and appium to automate the android app. I just want to click on incoming notification on status bar of android app in python script.
For exp: As someone sent message on Whatsapp, a notification regarding whatsapp message would receive. And when we clicking on it, it opens the whatsapp.So i want to click on notification using automation.